# How to write data on different files by using multithreading in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a multi-threaded server. Server accepts connections from different clients. Those clients send data periodically. My server has a standard multithreading code style like thread, run method etc. However, when I started a client, it sends data and during this process, when I start another client, first thread stops and second thread starts writing data to it's specific file. Another word,

Expected Results:

First thread's duration ---> 10 seconds data in the file1.txt,
Second thread's duration ---> 10 seconds data in the file2.txt,

Actual Results:

**First thread's duration --->Only 3 seconds of 10 seconds data in the file1.txt,(I started the second thread 3 seconds after starting the first thread)**
Second thread's duration ---> 10 seconds seconds data in the file2.txt

vice versa.

I want to write different multiple files by using multithreading.

Can you please help me with this problem ?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    public void run() {
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try {

            int x=0;
            while (runThread) {
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getRootDirectory() + fileName, true);
                for (int i = 17; i < requestData.length; i++) {
                    output.write(requestData[i]);
                }
                output.close();

                if (!ServerOn) {
                    System.out.print("Server has already stopped");
                    outputStream.println("Server has already stopped");
                    outputStream.flush();
                    m_bRunThread = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                myClientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("...Stopped");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you writing to the same file from multiple threads, you can expect corruption, you should either use file locks, or roll your own locking system to protect against this

Comment: Using multiple threads can allow you to either a) mitigate the network latency or b) use more CPU power if you have more CPUs, However it won't 1) make your network upload speed any faster 2) make your disk spin any faster.  You have to understand what your bottleneck is to know when using multiple threads will make any difference.

Comment: Most disks can write much faster than most internet connections. Even if you are using encryption and compression, you are most likely not limited by CPU. If you have more than a 1 Gbps connection, your network is almost certainly the bottleneck in which case, only increasing your network bandwidth will help.

Comment: I have to use connection because, that's kind of VoIP process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the generic example of 2 runing threads witch u can personalize it as u need , i hope it helps

```
 class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;

 RunnableDemo( String name){
    threadName = name;
    System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }
    public void run() {
  System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
  try {
     for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
        // Let the thread sleep for a while.
        Thread.sleep(50);
     }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
 }
 System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
}

public void start ()
{
  System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
  if (t == null)
  {
     t = new Thread (this, threadName);
     t.start ();
  }
}

}

public class TestThread {
public static void main(String args[]) {

  RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-1");
  R1.start();

  RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-2");
  R2.start();
}   
}
```